# Add methods to generated WCF client proxy code

Tags: code-generation, wcf-client, proxy-classes

I'd like to add one additional method for each service operation in my WCF client proxy code (i.e. the generated class that derives from `ClientBase`).  I have written a Visual Studio extension that has an `IOperationContractGenerationExtension` implementation, but this interface only seems to expose the ability to modify the service interface, not the `ClientBase`-derived class.

Is there any way to generate new methods in the proxy client class?

Comment: The IOperationContextGenerationExtension is indeed a server-side extension point for WCF. What is it that you want to achieve?? Just add a few methods to the proxy class? See my answer. Do something more??

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say that IOperationContextGenerationExtension is server-side.  It hooks into the import process and is therefore client-side (relative to the web service).  At least that's how I'm using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by generating a wrapper class for the ClientBase-derived class during the import process.  I actually first tried generating an additional partial class with the same name as the client class, but that caused the rest of the code generation to stop working properly.

So my final generated code looks something like:

(generated by the built-in WCF proxy generator):

```
public interface ServiceReference1
{
    IAsyncResult BeginWebMethod1(AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);
    void EndWebMethod1(IAsyncResult result);

    IAsyncResult BeginWebMethod2(AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);
    void EndWebMethod2(IAsyncResult result);

    // ...
}

public class ServiceReference1Client
{
    public event EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs> WebMethod1Completed;
    public event EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs> WebMethod2Completed;

    public void WebMethod1Async() { /* ... */ }
    public void WebMethod2Async() { /* ... */ }

    // ...
}
```

(generated by my custom `IOperationContractGenerationExtension`):

```
public class ServiceReference1Wrapper
{
    private ServiceReference1Client _client;

    public ServiceReference1Wrapper(ServiceReference1Client client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public IObservable<AsyncCompletedEventArgs> WebMethod1()
    {
        _client.WebMethod1Async();
        // ...
    }

    public IObservable<AsyncCompletedEventArgs> WebMethod2()
    {
        _client.WebMethod2Async();
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note: I'm using Silverlight, so that's why everything is async.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, those classes are always **partial classes**:

```
public partial class MyWCFServiceClient : ClientBase<IMyWCFService>, IMyWCFService 
{
  ...
}
```

so you can easily extend them with your own, second file that adds method to the same partial class:

**YourOwnFile.cs**

```
public partial class MyWCFServiceClient 
{
   public void NewMethod1()
   {
   }

   public void NewMethod2()
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What I'm trying to do though is to auto-generate the additional methods.  I'd like to avoid hand-writing them if at all possible.

Comment: @dcstraw: auto-generate based on what? What do these methods do? WCF has lots of extensibility points - both on the client and the server - but you'd have to be a bit more specific about what you're trying to do in order for us to be able to help and steer you in the right direction....

Comment: I want to add a method for each operation that returns an IObservable so that I can use Rx with the web service methods without having to manually create IObservables from the async events.